# Tiempo entre letras de una misma palabra

Tags: bash, shell

Quiero hacer un juego en el que el texto (que saldrá en la ventana shell) haga algo así:

```
H
Ho
Hol
Hola
```

Y que haga esto en la misma línea, con una espera de 0.1 segundos, pero no sé cómo, yo probé con esto:

```
print("H", sleep(0.1), "o", sleep(0.1), "l", sleep(0.1), "a")
```

Seguramente les parezca una estupidez pero es lo que se me ocurrió, y falló. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, todo lo que haces no está en Bash ni en alguna shell que yo conozca. Parece más pseudocódigo en Python. Por lo que tus comandos no servirán en alguna de esas (bash, dash, ash, zsh, fish).

Aún así, podrías intentar iterar por las letras de la palabra:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly palabra="hola"

for (( i = 0; i < "${#palabra}"; i++ )); do
#                       |
#                       |_ La longitud de la palabra    

    acumulado="${acumulado}${palabra:$i:1}"
#                                   |____|
#                                      |
#  Obtenemos una letra desde ----------
#+ la posicion que se incrementa
#+ y la añadimos a nuestro acumulado
    echo -en "\r$acumulado"
#  En esta parte vuelves al inicio de la misma linea
#+ y luego sobreescribes. Esto evitando el salto de linea
#+ que echo lanza por defecto
    sleep 1
done
```

Parte de la magia está en el `echo` y sus parámetros `-n` que evita el salto de línea al final de lo impreso, y `-e` que habilita algunos caracteres de control como `\r` que indica que el cursos se va a mostrar al inicio de la línea, y desde ahí comenzará a escribir.

De esta manera sobreescribe el "h" con "ho", y luego el "ho" con "hol", etc.

Lo guardas en un archivo, digamos, de nombre "numeros". Luego le das permisos de ejecución:

```
$ chmod u+x ./numeros
```

Y lo ejecutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]